# React Native App Transport Security has blocked

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, react-native-image

I just installed react-native-image-crop.
When I tried to make a photo on an actual iPhone, I received a quite strange error. `'App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource load since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via your app's Info.plist file.'`. Is this because I using the metro builder? or something else maybe?

My Info.plist:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>localhost</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Transport security has blocked a cleartext HTTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31254725/transport-security-has-blocked-a-cleartext-http)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to add this key in Info.plist
[image]

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Comment: This looks good!
The ArbitraryLoads were missing!
Thanks mate :)

Comment: This is not working for new apps builds, with no exception