# Why React-Native doesn't show data fetched by Axios?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, axios

I've installed `axios` by this command:

```
npm i axios
```

I wrote the code below and everything I think is correct but React-Native doesn't show any data and throw any errors:

```js
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

import {
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet
} from 'react-native';

const App = () => {
    
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get('http://localhost:8000/posts').then(res => {
            setData(res.data);
        });
    }, []);
    
    return (
        <View style={styles.mainBody}>
            {
                
                data.map(item => (
                    <View>
                        <Text>{item.fields.title}</Text>
                    </View>
                ))
                
            }
        </View>
    );
};
```

- I've tested `functional` and `class-based` components for this.
- I fetch data with **Postman** and works correctly.
- I added `.catch` and it shows this: `Error: Network Error`

But it doesn't work on React-Native and because of no errors, I can't understand what's my problem. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is it because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51363339/react-native-app-transport-security-has-blocked)?

Comment: @Adam I don't have any error.

Comment: A lack of data is an error. Please provide details - does the fetch complete? Does it even fire in the first place? Does the fetch hang indefinitely? Does it eventually throw (if you added a catch)?

Comment: @Adam How should I check it in React-Native that fetch is fired in the first place?

Comment: Maybe chain a .catch to catch the error and try adding debugger before the call and follow the trace.

Comment: @Ray I added `.catch` and it shows this: `Error: Network Error`

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're using localhost in your URL, with react-native we cant use localhost but instead, we use the IPv4 address of our computer. So click on your  wifi icon then click on the properties then look for `IPv4 address` something like: 193.93.443

So if to say your IPv4 address is 193.93.443, the local URL will be like this: http://193.93.443:8000/posts

Comment: I found the `IPv4` address by `ipconfig` command in CMD. I added as you said but nothing changed.

Comment: Your phone and your computer needs to be in the same WiFi connection.

Comment: It's an emulator. They're same. I'm using Django for API. Nothing to do with Django?

Comment: Your can test your back-end with something like postman to be sure of whether it's working as expected. So as far as it's working smoothly on Postman then surely the issue is with your front-end. And that of emulator, I actually have never worked with it, I test my application on physical device. But be sure that you're not behind any proxy or using VPN.